# My app doesn't respond to change in preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

i'm trying to make the user choose the time of alarm but the alarm keeps triggering every 15 minutes "which is default" even if i choose another preference

this is the code related to the problem in my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static String reminder;
private static AlarmManager am;
private ImageButton btn;
private ImageButton cancel;
private EditText et;
private Intent intent;
private PendingIntent pend;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // initialize variables
    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    cancel = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // create intents
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);
    pend = getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    // get the user preference
    String sel = sp.getString("repeatPref", "1");
    final String repeat[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.settings_repeat_by_labels);
    final int ss = Integer.parseInt(sel);
    // action when user presses the "Tweak" button
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pend.cancel();
            am.cancel(pend);
            // initialize pend and AlarmManager
            pend = getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            // if the user didn't type anything
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                // notify at different times
                if (repeat[ss - 1].equals("15 MINUTES")) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 60*1000 ,60*1000, pend);
                    }
                } else if (repeat[ss - 1].equals("1 HOUR")) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 120 * 1000, 120 * 1000, pend);
                    }
                } else if (repeat[ss - 1].equals("2 HOURS")) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 2, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 2, pend);
                    }

    });
```

another button to cancel the alarm

```
 cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                am.cancel(pend);
                pend.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"All cleared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

         });
```

i'm creating the pend and Alarm In the onCreate method and second time when the "btn" is pressed because i'm creating another button to cancel it and i tried "for long time" to check if the PendingIntent "pend" and AlarmManager "am" already exist or no and then depending on the result canceling it but i failed so i thought this approach might work

Now everytime the user wants to cancel alarm and open the app it will create new pending intent and Alarm manager so if the user presses the cancel button without pressing "btn" first The app don't crash and the alarm which was already working gets canceled..i suspect this is part of the problem i'm having now

i know it's alot of stuff but i tried explaining as simple as possible..thanks for taking time to read all of that!

Answer (score 0):

My app wasn't responding to my changes because I was retrieving the shared preferences before I click "btn". It got fixed after I moved the shared preference part to the onClick method.